# For high scalability & performance needs, is it preferable to have C++ or Java implementation at the backend of a PHP application?

Tags: c#, c++, c, jakarta-ee

For high scalability & performance needs for a social portal, is it advisable to have C++ or Java implementation at the backend of an PHP application ?

What are the benefits & trade-offs of the same ?

Comment: PHP backed off by Java? That would be a really odd setup. Facebook do it all in PHP. Thinking about architecture would probably serve you better than thinking about platform. Why is C# in your tags?

Comment: actually the primary reason for business logic in java was that we wanted to interact with cassandra database through its java client called Hector... Do you think C++ would lead to performance boosts as compared to entire PHP implementation ?

Comment: Facebook is not doing everything in PHP. PHP is slow as molasses. Facebook uses a mix of PHP, Java, Erlang, C++ in the various layers of their architecture. It even translates PHP into C++ to get better performance. And they soon realized that the LAMP stack doesn't cut it when you are talking about millions of users in a social network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In raw performance terms, C++ will get you a fair bit further than Java or PHP, and slightly further than C#. By this I mean that if you implement the same algorithm in these different languages you are most likely to see the best performance from C++ (although it will depend exactly on what you're doing and how you do it - a different language on its own is not a magic bullet; you need to learn how to make the best use of that language, which can take years).

As @spender has said, using well thought out algorithms and architecture will usually give a greater gain in performance and a much greater gain in scalability than simply switching to a different language might achieve. Performance is fundamentally about being efficient (minimising your *usage* of resources like bandwidth, memory, disk and CPU) and scalabilty is primarily about making things work well in parallel (minimising *contention* for resources like data, bandwidth, memory and CPU, and minimising the need for different parts of your system to communicate with each other)

As @Kugel said, if you have a truly scalable architecture then you can to some extent just throw more hardware at the problem, which might initially be a cheaper approach than rewriting everything in a different language. However, if your site is successful, making your code as efficient as possible will reduce your hardware and running costs.

Another consideration may be development/maintainability related - if you are an expert in PHP and a newbie at C++, you may well squeeze more out of PHP than you can out of C++. You have to consider the whole picture and work out what is the most "commercially viable" solution, not just what is the theoretically highest performing one. Or you may find that your "thrown together and works surprisingly well" PHP solution is up and running in a week while your highly optimised C++ never quite gets finished.

Comment: actually a main reason for considering Java/C++ at this stage was that we need to interact with Cassandra database using a client option that is developed for Java or C++. The client for PHP is not fully mature and has limitations. Thus I was thinking of implementing the full app in Java or otherwise just the backend alone in Java.

Comment: @Marcos: That's a good example of something that may well make the language decision clear-cut. Also, if you're waiting for a database, it's worth considering that most of the execution time may actually be in the database layer, and so your choice of language may not have much impact on the overall time taken to deliver a page - Java and C++ may work out virtually identical if the database query is the bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't writing the next facebook. Write it in PHP (or whatever language you're most comfortable with) for now. If you're lucky enough to grow large enough to the point where php can't handle the load then you can redesign your site. Unless you're running one of the top 100 sites it the world you're just engaged in premature optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all PHP is already a backend. PHP itself is implemented in C or C++.

For scalability language doesn't matter, because scalability is about parallel handling of multiple requests.

For performance as in "get a single request processed as soon as possible", language usually matters that's why Facebook wrote PHP to C++ compiler.

Comment: I need to do some processing of the data after retrieving from the database & before it is served to the client. That's why I think it may be good to implement the business logic in C++ or some other powerful language. Or do you think PHP can handle that without performance degradation ?

Comment: Has facebook converted its business logic code into C++ ? I guess through HipHop right? Does this really lead to performace boosts?

Comment: Unles you do some statistical or financial calculations, I don't think you will need c++ solution. Usually language is the last bottleneck. First database will be an issue with a lot of users.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your definition of "high" and dozens of other factors. Usually performance should be just "enough". From my experience, trying to write the fastest possible implementation from start can backfire badly. As to language choice IMO it depends more on people writing the code and their experience with the problem domain.